# Visual Studio Code can't run Python file with F5 but can run it by clicking the top right corner menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I hit F5 to run my script, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.txt'`

The setting to execute it in the script's directory is turned on.

[image]

But! The script runs fine if I try it from terminal or if I click the Run Python button in the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: `F5` use the launch config, create a launch config to run your script in the debugger

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @rioV8, the `F5` shortcut invokes the launch configuration. Make sure that your `.vscode/launch.json` file has something like this (it will launch the active file in VS Code):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // This config executes only the current file.
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

It looks like either you don't have a `launch.json` or your attribute `program` is somehow pointing to `input.txt`.

You can also set a specific file path to always run that file (no matter which file is active at the moment).